# Printing list elements - How are these two solutions different?

Tags: prolog

I am currently going through "Programming in Prolog" by Clocksin & Mellish. One of the exercises asks to print list elements each on a line while indenting nested elements, so for example we need to print [a,b,[c,d],e,f] as:

```
a
b
   c
   d
e
f
```

So, here is my solution (assume we have a predicate 'indent' that prints a specified no. of spaces for indentation). I have defined two predicates 'print' & 'printelement', each takes a first argument to be printed and a second for the indentation (no. of spaces):

```
print([],_).
print([H|T],Indent):- H\=[_|_],                        % if not a list
                      printelement(H,Indent),             
                      print(T,Indent).

print([H|T],Indent):- H=[_|_], NewIndent is Indent+2,  % if a list, increase the indent
                      print(H,NewIndent),              % NewIndent
                      print(T,Indent).                 % Indent

printelement(X,I):- indent(I), write(X), nl.           % print individual elements
```

... and it does the job. On the other hand, the book presents a solution that does the job too but with a bit of going back and forth between two predicates as follows:

```
printA([H|T], I) :- !, J is I + 2, printA(H, J), printB(T, J), nl.
printA(X, I) :- indent(I), write(X), nl.

printB([],_).
printB([H|T], I) :- printA(H, I), printB(T, I).
```

There are a number of other exercises that are solved in a similar manner; and even though I can trace those solutions and validate their correctness, I am a bit confused by this approach. So, would you please help point out the differences between the above solutions? I find mine a bit more logical and straight-forward, and I don't quite get the second one!

Comment: `printA` handles *elements*, and if these turn out to be lists, then it will make a call to `printA` to render the *sublist*, whereas `printB` handles a list by calling `printA` on that element and recurse on the rest of the list.

Comment: As an aside, you should be careful *not* to use generic predicate names, like `print`, for your own predicates. You stand the risk of attempting to redefine existing system predicates. Many programming languages, including SWI Prolog, have a `print` predicate or function themselves.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you I get it ... How about my solution in comparison to the second one? I mean, should I start to think in a similar manner as that of the book?

Comment: @lurker Thank you, point taken!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to pick between the two solutions, I actually prefer the first solution to the one in the textbook. At least I see no advantages to the second approach, and both solutions are a fairly imperative approach to Prolog. If you had a big enough list, you could do a performance comparison, if that was an important factor. Both have a somewhat awkward calling convention where you need to provide a second argument even though you don't care what it is, ultimately.  The second solution has the two arbitrarily named predicates `printA` and `printB` that don't seem to have a distinguishable enough semantic meaning between them. You can call `printA(MyList, 0).` or `printB(MyList, 0).` and get (sort of) the same results (one having one extra level of indent).

Both `printA/2` and `print/2` treat `[]` as an atom rather than an empty list. Thus:

```
| ?- print([a,b,[],c], 0).
a
b
[]
c
```

And similarly for `printA([a,b,[],c], 0).`

If I were writing this, I would take a different approach altogether. First, I might write a predicate with 3 arguments: `element_depth(List, X, D)` that succeeds if `X` is in the multi-level list `List` at depth `D` and it fails otherwise.

```
element_depth(List, X, Depth) :-
    element_depth(List, X, 0, Depth).  % Starts with depth 0

element_depth([X|_], X, Depth, Depth) :-
    \+ is_list(X).
element_depth([L|_], X, D, Depth) :-
    is_list(L),
    D1 #= D + 1,
    element_depth(L, X, D1, Depth).
element_depth([_|Xs], X, D, Depth) :-
    element_depth(Xs, X, D, Depth).
```

Now you have a Prolog predicate that behaves more like a predicate and less like a C function. You use it to make queries and it provides solutions. You can do queries such as:

```
| ?- element_depth([a,b,[d, []], c], X, D).

D = 0
X = a ? a

D = 0
X = b

D = 1
X = d

D = 0
X = c

no
| ?- element_depth([a,b,[d,[]], c], X, 1).

X = d ? ;

no
| ?- element_depth([a,b,[d,[]], c], c, D).

D = 0 ? ;

no
```

If you want to do a formatted printing of results, you can write a specific formatting predicate that calls it:

```
print_elements(L) :-
    element_depth(L, X, D),
    N #= D * 2,
    indent(N),
    write(X), nl,
    fail.
```

Which you can then call like this:

```
| ?- print_elements([a,b,[d,[]], c]).
a
b
  d
c

no
| ?-
```

This looks like a little more code, but it is more general and more Prology.

Comment: Thank you @lurker for your detailed answer! I like your pointing out 'the imperative approach to Prolog' which I am still figuring out how to overcome and think more 'Prology'.

Comment: Would you recommend a better source that would help me approach problems the Prolog way?

Comment: @Kazumi: perhaps first think of them as *first-order clauses*. So how would you *define* a relation in logic. There are no "instructions". You can only *declare* predicates.

Comment: Thank you @WillemVanOnsem for following up.